# Fractional factorial photographic questionnaire scenarios when I can't represent every option

Tags: choice-modeling, fractional-factorial

Background: I am looking to do a DCE questionnaire on consumer preferences for a certain product. The scenarios are represented by photographs of the different products. Since the features and levels that the products vary at are too great to do a full factorial analysis, I will do a fractional factorial. I want to use conditional logit to analyze the responses.

Problem: Within my set of photographs, not all scenarios (i.e. products with specific attributes) I should ideally be using in my fractional factorial analysis are represented. Some of the products don't exist yet so I don't have photographs of them. The features are too complex for me to manipulate the photographs in order to include them. In my mind I have a few options:

- Manually change the choice sets to include scenarios that are similar but not quite the ones I should be using
- Drop features that are strongly underrepresented in the photographs
- Use a completely different design instead of DCE

What are some recommended options in this scenario?